# ios Passing TextView from PushView to PresentingView

Tags: ios, uitextview, pushviewcontroller, uitextviewdelegate

I am trying to do the following, and not able to find a straightforward answer.. It is related to this :[Passing uitextfield from one view to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212908/passing-of-uitextfield-text-from-one-view-to-another). But not exactly.

I have a Firstview.m, from which I push to a Secondview.m. The Secondview.m has a UITextView. I allow the user to edit the UITextView on Secondview.m. Now I want to store this text value in a variable in Firstview.m. One way to to do this is as follows

in Firstview.h

```
@property (nonatomic) Secondview *secondView;
```

That is keep a secondView variable in Firstview itself. But this doesn't seem efficient. Ideally I should only have 1 NSString text field in FirstView. What is the right way to do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Delegation in Objective-C.

In your `SecondView.h` add following right after Header Inclusion

```
@protocol YourDelegateName <NSObject>
   -(void)setText:(NSString *)strData;
@end
```

Also add delegate property to your header for accessing them in calling class, like below (This goes with other properties declaration in `SecondView.h` file):

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<YourDelegateName> delegate;
```

Now, Comes the calling the delegate part. Say, you want to save the text value of `UITextView` of `SeconView` in `strTextViewData` of `FirstView` class, when the following event occurs:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate setText:self.txtView.text]; // Assuming txtView is name for UITextView object
}
```

Now, In `FirstView.h` add `YourDelegateName` in delegate list like below:

```
@interface FisrtView : ViewController <YourDelegateName>
    @property (nonatomic, reatin) NSString *strTextViewData;
@end
```

And then in `FisrtView.m` file when you create instance of `SecondView` class, set delegate to `self` like below:

```
SecondView *obj = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SeconView" bundle:nil];
obj.delegate = self; // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART. DON'T MISS THIS.
```

Now, Implement the delegate method:

```
-(void)setText:(NSString *)strData
{
     self.strTextViewData = strData;
}
```

Applying this to your code will do what you want. Also, Delegation is one of the most important feature of Objective-C language, which - by doing this - you will get to learn.

Let me know, if you face any issue with this implementation.

Comment: Some explanation about Delegate would be great within the answer, as this answer cover the topic with minimal code.

Comment: @richa Thanks a lot. That explanation is really helpful, and delegates is the right thing to learn for me here..

When I executed the code you gave, I get the following error..

`Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x27c7ff4)`

I absolutely don't understand what this means. Am I missing something obvious here ? Thanks!

Comment: The only difference in my code and what you gave is that I am instantiating the SecondView using Storyboard as follows..
`UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];`
`SecondView *sView = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondView"];
`

Comment: I am basically running into an infinite loop.. trying to understand what's wrong ...

Comment: @user3580099 as I have mentioned there. Setting the delegate to self is an important part. Are you sure you have set the delegate to self, properly?

Comment: Hi Richa, Thanks a lot. I actually found my mistake. I was using NSString *text as a variable, and using setText which was getting confused with the setter of the variable. Really bad mistake on my part. Your code was really helpful! Thanks a lot! And delegates are brilliant1